# RBAC permissions on SQL Graph

Tags: sql, postgresql, graph, access-control

New poster, so please beat me up with the additional questions / critiques as I get the etiquette correct.  I'm currently implementing a for fun social network solution.  The premise is to use off the shelf technology and traditional SQL tooling (ideally PostgreSQL 9.4+) to create a graph for sharing notes, pictures, and eventually other social artifacts with traditional read write PBAC system.  I'm mostly interested in graphs of "moderate" density (est. approximately 1 node to every 10 edges, approximately 150k nodes is where I want to start - napkin math).  My SQL experience is mostly limited consumption, but graphs / data modeling have fascinated me for some time.  I understand that Neo4j and cousins offers O(1) query traversals and an awesome query language, but I'm looking strictly to implement a classical RDBMS implementation (I like my databases locked down with query explanations and such.  This is a PoC project as much as a for fun excursion :) ).

I am aware I am abusing RDBMS for this project.  The question is, given people's experiences, how do we abuse it the least while preserving the graph database structure AND strict access control requirements?

PBAC reference for the not so security guru: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Access_Control_Cheat_Sheet#tab=Permission_Based_Access_Control

The crux / rules of the problem is as follows.

- Users exist.
- Roles exist.
- Permissions exist - see link above.
- A user can have many roles.
- A role can have many permissions.
- A user must have the corresponding read / write permission to access a graph node or edge.
- A node or edge initially is created with only a read / write permission ID for the user.
- A user MUST see their own notes.
- A user MAY provision a note to be shared with another role OR user.

Two immediate solutions jump to mind.

1. I could use the traditional many to many relationship model.  I could create many-to-many permission to node/edge tables, then provide the table joins to check actions against the node/edge tables.  This has the upside of supporting traditional access checks we see in generic web applications and is easier to test / audit (possible assumption based on experience?).  The downside is that I will have a harder time cross correlating my users with each other when it comes to what notes each user shares / accesses (separate tables).  I initially tried this and found that my DAOs were quickly getting muddled together / cross dependent on each other.
2. I could embed the user, roles, and permissions with the notes in the SQL graph as nodes with attached access edges.  The downside to this approach is that I hit the graph tables for practically every new feature I add to the web application, drastically increasing my dependence on vertical scaling if I were to take what I learn elsewhere.  My edge table would probably explode exponentially in side with respect to the nodes table.  Plus side, this might allow me to scale horizontally somewhere down the road.  However, I would gain a simpler access model. I believe this is called GBAC? [GBAC on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph-based_access_control)

Other thoughts

- I intend to use UUID4 for primary key index as it SHOULD allow horizontal scaling if I wanted to hack that direction.
- I intend to make the "value" field on PgSQL JSONB with a "value" key w/GIN index.  This is under the assumption that most users know the beginning bit of what they want.

I've gotten so far into this question that I realize I've lost my notes.  I will try and find my crow foot diagrams / DAO pseudo-code.

So the questions at hand are as follows.

1. Given my desire for strict access control as a primary concern, does anyone have experience implementing this de-normalized schema?  Which issues and trade-offs did you take to get around the expected performance bottlenecks of case 2 (if any)?  If you went with case 1, was the added many-to-many query worth the additional maintenance and effort?
2. Are there any suggested reference materials in this vain of inquiry which may offer guidance?  I feel like I'm in a bizarre place.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, @kloid23  You will have a better change of getting good answers by choosing to focus on more narrow issue and a single question that is less opinion driven.

Comment: Thank you @Degan !  I'll try and refine my question.  There's not a great deal out there, so I stopped lurking. :)

Comment: you may want to review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for some pointers on creating a good question.